# Adding template in vue CLI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to setup a template in vue js. I am using cli and also made R&D on this. But its not working. My project folder structure is

```
 ->dist/index.html
 ->node_modules
 ->public/index.html
 ->src 
     assets
     components
     router
     views
```

**Where I put template html file and external css or js file. How to include them.** 
 I am beginner in vue js.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your CSS file into `src/assets` and your external JS file into `public` folder. Your single-file Vue components (the `templates` as you call them) will reside in `src/views` folder. As a beginner you should start by reading the official Vue documentation and examples on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Thanks for your reply in **App.vue**  i added **@import 'assets/styles/styles.css';** . but it showing error **[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.**

Comment: Maybe your App.vue is missing its `<template>` or its `<script>` section ? Every Vue component **must** have either a template - or a render function.